# Machine Learning liner Regression - Sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm new to the Machine learning domain and in Learn Regression i have some doubt

1:While practicing the sklearn learn regression model prediction method getting the below error.

Code:

```
sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.predict(25)
```

Error: 
 "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead: array=25. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."

Do i need to pass a 2-D array? Checked on sklearn documentation page any haven't found any thing for version update.
 **Running my code on Kaggle
https://www.kaggle.com/aman9d/bikesharingdemand-upx/

2: Is index of dataset going to effect model's score (weights)?

Comment: Please seriously consider correcting typos in your code (`predice`??) and in your (dead) link...

Comment: Link is working, and yes here its typo but in code i written correctly and getting the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should put your code as you use:

```
# import, instantiate, fit
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
linreg = LinearRegression()
linreg.fit(X, y)

# use the predict method
linreg.predict(25)
```

Because what you post in the question is not properly executable, `predict` method is not static for the class `LinearRegression`.

When you fit a model, the first step is recognize which kind of data will be the input, in your case will be similar to `X`, that means that if you pass something with different shape of `X` to the model it will raise an error.

In your example `X` seems to be a pd.DataFrame() instance with only 1 column, this should be replaceable with an array of 2 dimension representing the number of examples by the number of features, so if you try:

```
linreg.predict([[25]])
```

should work.

For example if you were trying a regression with more than 1 feature aka column, let's say `temp` and `humidity`, your input would look like this:

```
linreg.predict([[25, 56]])
```

I hope this will help you and always keep in mind which is the shape of your data.

Documentation: [LinearRegression fit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit)

> X : array-like or sparse matrix, shape (n_samples, n_features)

Answer (score 1):

I think the **predict() method** of scikit-learn .... **LinearRegression model** expects a 2D array as input, even if you are predicting a single value.
To fix the error, you can reshape the input value using either **array.reshape(-1, 1) or array.reshape(1, -1).**